# Accessibility widget solution for a Gatsby.js site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, accessibility, gatsby

I have made a website for a client with gatsby.js, for which an additional requirement (aside from the usual accessibility checklist) is the integration of an accessibility widget, much like [this one](https://accessibility-widget.pages.dev/). The aforementioned is the only free solution I have found, but that doesn't seem to be working on my Gatsby site. I did a trial on a vanilla js site and that works as expected.

My question is: is there anyone that has tried anything similar for a Gatsby site? I have done some research on this and almost all solutions are paid, and I can't seem to be able to find any reliable documentation to integrate those on a Gatsby site.

I tried the Sienna widget, but it doesn't seem to be working.